# Configure unity with one config file for multiple applications

Tags: .net, configuration, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have two closely related applications that are both using the Unity IoC container. They have some custom types in common, but not all of them. At the moment I have two config files that have a lot of duplication. I'd like to have just one Unity config file to rule them all.

However, as not all types exist in both applications Unity is unhappy. What I want is a way to tell Unity not to try and register/instantiate the types in the config file unless the container is asked for them.

I can think of a couple of solutions but as I'm a Unity newbie I don't want to guess/reinvent.

And yes, it must be Unity. For now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like an extension, have a look at,

[Is there TryResolve in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878994/is-there-tryresolve-in-unity/901783#901783)

and see if it help you out.

Comment: I think that this answers the question. Thanks! 
I'm still not sure if this is the right way to go. I did think about using a shared container for the common elements and a child container for the specifics, but then you have 3 files instead of 2!