# Unity XML Config Test

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, dependency-injection, unity-container

We are constantly having problem with our application being broken due to the Unity configuration not being able to resolve dependencies, either the dll or namespace has been changed or is initially wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for writing a Test that will ensure all the Unity config files can resolve their dependencies?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this question may be of help to you:

[Is there TryResolve in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878994/is-there-tryresolve-in-unity)