# Unity - loadConfiguration, how to resolve only those configured

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

What I am trying to achieve: Have Unity load the mappings from a configuration file, then in source code resolve the types which were loaded from said configuration file

App.Config

```
<register type="NameSpace.ITill, ExampleTightCoupled" mapTo="NameSpace.Till, NameSpace" />
<register type="NameSpace.IAnalyticLogs, NameSpace" mapTo="NameSpace.AnalyticLogs, NameSpace" />
```

Code

```
IUnityContainer container;
container = new UnityContainer();

// Read interface->type mappings from app.config
container.LoadConfiguration();

// Resolve ILogger - this works
ILogger obj = container.Resolve<ILogger>();

// Resolve IBus - this fails
IBus = container.Resolve<IBus>();
```

Issue: Sometimes IBus will be defined in the App.config, and sometimes it will not be there. When I try and resolve an interface/class and it does not exist I get an exception.

Can someone educate me here?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Prevent coming in this situation all together. If `IBus` is an optional dependency, create and register a [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) implementation (an empty implementation that is effectively a no-op). This prevents you from having to complicate your application logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Unity are you using? In v2+ there is an extension method:

```
public static bool IsRegistered<T>(this IUnityContainer container);
```

so you can do

```
if (container.IsRegistered<IBus>())
    IBus = container.Resolve<IBus>();
```

An extension method would make this nicer

```
public static class UnityExtensions
{
    public static T TryResolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container.IsRegistered<T>())
            return container.Resolve<T>();

        return default(T);
    }
}

// TryResolve returns the default type (null in this case) if the type is not configured
IBus = container.TryResolve<IBus>();
```

Also check out this link: [Is there TryResolve in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878994/is-there-tryresolve-in-unity)

Comment: One [big warning](https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/392550) about the `IsRegistered` method: It is only meant for debugging because it is notoriously slow! It has a performance characteristic of O(n) and can completely drown the performance of your application.

Comment: TryResolve doesn't always return null -- it is returning the default value for the type (which is null for reference types).  But if resolving an int, for example, 0 will be returned. Also, it might be nice to align with the Unity Resolve method and support ResolverOverrides as well as the name override.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware it'll return the default type, I meant it'll return null for IBus. I'll update the comment to reflect that.